# Unable to install pycocotools on Google AI-Platform (CMLE)

Tags: python, cython, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training, pycocotools

I'm getting this error while `trainer` package installation on AI-Platform,

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in
>    File "/tmp/pip-install-_u8thvm6/pycocotools/setup.py", line
>   2, in  from Cython.Build import cythonize ImportError: No
>   module named 'Cython'

Although I've included `'Cython'` in `setup.py`.

**setup.py:**

```py
import setuptools

NAME = 'trainer'
VERSION = '1.0'
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'Cython', # Cython, mentioned before pycocotools
    'tensorflow-gpu',
    'google-cloud-storage',
    'gcsfs',
    'pycocotools'
]

setuptools.setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    description='Trainer package')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install cython before running setup.py. The problem is that cython is needed at build time, not runtime, and there’s no guarantee about which order the packages you listed in `install_requires` get installed. So when pip tries to install `pycocotools` it hasn’t yet installed cython and aborts.

Answer (score 1):

By adding these lines in `setup.py` the error is solved,

```py
import setuptools

# Install cython before setup
import os                                       # <--- This line added
os.system('pip3 install --upgrade cython')      # <--- This line added

NAME = 'trainer'
VERSION = '1.0'
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'Cython', # Cython, mentioned before pycocotools
    'tensorflow-gpu',
    'google-cloud-storage',
    'gcsfs',
    'pycocotools'
]

setuptools.setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    description='Trainer package')
```

Comment: Definitely don't do this for any code you distribute to people. Just import cython and raise an error if you get an ImportError suggesting to install cython.